# Convert javascript string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, literals, string-literals

I'm retrieving an array of objects from a hidden html input field.  The string I'm getting is:

```
"{"id":"1234","name":"john smith","email":"jsmith@blah.com"},{"id":"4431","name":"marry doe","email":"mdoe@blah.com"}"
```

Now I need to pass this as an array  of objects again. How do I convert this string into array of objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var array_of_objects = eval("[" + my_string + "]");
```

This executes the string as code, which is why we need to add the [] to make it an object. This is also one of the few legitimate uses for eval as its the fastest and easiest way. :D

Comment: FYI, you can also use JSON.parse method if you are using JSON parser library. Thanks SLaks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710556/convert-javascript-string-to-an-array/2710558#2710558

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that `str` holds valid JSON syntax, you can simply call `eval(str)`.

For security reasons, it's better to use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), like this:

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

Note that `str` must be wrapped in `[]` to be a valid JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

There are many bad formatted string object, GET from API, old code, etc. Bad format doesn't means it drops error in code, but drops error for input of JSON.parse().

```
// not " wrapped key syntax
var str = "{ a: 2 }";
console.log( JSON.parse( str ) );
//  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

// 'key', or 'value' syntax
var str = " { 'a': 2 } ";
console.log( JSON.parse( str ) );
// SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

//syntax OK
var str = '{ "a": 2 }';
console.log( JSON.parse( str ) );
// Object { a: 2 }
```

There is a solution:

```
// Convert any-formatted object string to well formatted object string:
var str = "{'a':'1',b:20}";
console.log( eval( "JSON.stringify( " + str + ", 0, 1 )" ) );

/* 
"{
 "a": "1",
 "b": 20
}"
*/

// Convert any-formatted object string to object:
console.log( JSON.parse(  eval( "JSON.stringify( " + str + ", 0, 1 )" ) ) );
// Object { a: "1", b: 20 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str=eval([{'id':'1','txt':'name1'},{'id':'2','txt':'name2'},{'id':'3','txt':'name3'}])
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
alert(str[i].txt);
}
```